# will visual studio 2012 projects open in visual studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Has anyone tried it?
I need to open my projects soon in a computer with visual studio 2010 installed.
Will they open, should I change any setting?

Comment: What kind of projects?

Comment: If they are using .Net 4.5 (or later), which I believe is the default for VS2012, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what features you have in your 2012 projects.  Some of the 2012 features will not open in 2010 and will therefore need upgrading.  To quote Microsoft:

"If you use both Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2010 SP1, you can create and modify projects and files in either version as long as you don't add features that require Visual Studio 2012."

More details on the features that are not supported in 2010 can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh266747.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I did try it and it worked, but the catch is that you should use only features or settings to the projects that are available to Visual Studio 2010, otherwise it won't be able to open or build the projects.